Movie about a rich and poor girl who become friends through a home swap
This movie is probably from the 1990s. 
It's about two girls in a high school that fight a lot. One is poor and the other is rich. In the beginning of the movie, they set fire to a locker room in the school. Their punishment is that they have to trade homes and do community service together. 
Over time, they become friends. 
In the end, the rich girl becomes the prom queen. The poor girl is happy for her. The poor girl ends up dating rich girl's brother. 

Sounds like The Great Mom Swap from 1995 with Valerie Harper.

Terri Venessi (Mary Kate Schellhardt), a local smart girl and deli girl, always seems to be at odds with the [rich] cheerleading captain, Karen Ridgeway (Hillary Tuck). One day their pranks on each other go too far and the school has to close as a result [after almost burning down]. The girls have to perform community service. A juvenile counselor tells them that the girls should switch lives for a while to experience the other girl's life. The counselor also notices that both mothers act the same way toward each other.

And it ends like you say (the poor girl likes the rich girl's brother, and the rich girl's voted prom queen). Here's a clip (from a Sid Caesar scene):



